# Rollback hitten endpoint's when internet connection is gone

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage

In my react-native app, i have a registerScreen where user registers himself. So in the registration process 4 endpoints are getting hit.

All i want to do is, if in case after hitting first endpoint internet connection is gone, how do we rollback it?

What im trying is im saving four string's in local storage for four endpoints in componentDidMount() like:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("one", "endPointOne");
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("two", "endPointTwo");
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("three", "endPointThree");
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("four", "endPointFour");
    }
```

Im checking the criteria in way:

```
    let endPoint_one = await AsyncStorage.getItem("one");
    if(endPoint_one === "endPointOne") { hitEndPointOne }
```

And as the endpoints are getting success, endpoints are removed from local storage, like:

```
    try {
        axios.post(${SERVER_URL}${ENDPOINT_ONE})
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.status !== 200) {
                    dispatch({
                        type: REQ_1_FAIL
                    });
                    return 0;
                }
                AsyncStorage.remove("one");
            })
    } catch(err) { dispatch({type: ERR})}
```

The problem starts here, as first endpoint gets hit and internet connection goes off and user closes the app.

After the user starts the app again, on registration page componentDidMount() is called again and the four endpoints are stored again locally which causes to call the first endpoint again and so onn to the remaining endpoints even if they are completed

After first attempt of registration, its getting messed...
Is there any specific or standard way to do so?